# Can you debug Karma test runner?

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

I'm new to Karma and node.js.  I am trying to run my Karma test but I get an error with an unhelpful message.

Is there any way I can debug my test to see where the problem is?

Comment: This is a very specific question and I understand what I am trying to do.

The question was put on hold claiming "Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved."  However, I do not see this rule or guideline anywhere on the site.  And while my understanding is not advanced, I do have enough understanding to know what the problem is and to ask about it.  

It is also worth noting that a simple Google search does not answer the question.

Comment: You can rephrase the question and put some error here to help us. On answering your question. Debug button on right top opens a new page which allows you to debug your test case like other javasript application using Script tab... Hope this helps..

Comment: Voting up, because question is direct and can be answered objectively.

Comment: I have this same question, shame it was closed.  I don't think whoever closed this understood what the OP was asking.

Comment: Here, maybe this incredibly useful error message will help:

`Chrome 31.0.1650 (Mac OS X 10.9.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.892 secs / 0 secs)`

That's literally ALL Karma is giving me right now. What else could OP have offered?

Comment: This question seems terribly reasonable.  There is almost no information on how to debug node tests online.  This leaves users in a state where they can't even get to the point of an error message.  All they (I) have is a failing test that you want to debug.  Coming from .NET, sure, this question should be closed as "minimal understanding" because debugging is so easy, easier than running without debugging!  But in the Node world that is far from the case and there is no obvious answer.

Comment: @david Yes, if he had an error message like that he should have included it in the post.